# Drop duplicate rows from a dataframe based on values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, in-place

| email | date | name | completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:40:00 | james | no |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:10:00 | james | yes |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:19:00 | james | yes |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:30:00 | james | no |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:04:00 | clark | yes |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:08:00 | clark | yes |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:13:00 | clark | no |
| bbb@xyz.com | 02-07-2022 08:28:00 | clark | no |

In the above dataframe, i want to drop multiple rows associated with name/email-id and retain the earliest time.

Output

| email | date | name | completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 12:10:00 | james | yes |
| aaa@xyz.com | 01-07-2022 08:04:00 | clark | yes |

This is what i have tried;

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
df = df.groupby('date').first()
```

This ends up creating date as an index. I don't want the column i am sorting on to be created as an index, i want to sort in place. Basically, i want to get the earliest 'date' for each name and email. Both 'name' and 'email' columns have duplicate values, the only differentiating factor is the values in the 'date' column. Out of all the values in the 'date' column for a particular person, i want to only retain the earliest date when completed = 'yes' and drop all the other rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby(['email', 'name']).first().reset_index()
```

gives

| index | email | name | date | completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aaa@xyz.com | james | 01-07-2022 12:10:00 | yes |
| 1 | bbb@xyz.com | clark | 02-07-2022 08:04:00 | yes |

Comment: This solution works out great! but it ends up creating email as an index. how do i prevent that from happening?

Comment: By adding `.reset_index()` - see adjusted answer. Just to be precise: without `.reset_index()`, we would actually have a multiindex consisting of `['email', 'name']`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.groupby` followed by `.idxmin()`:

```py
print(df[df.completed == "yes"].loc[df.groupby(["email", "name"])["date"].idxmin()])
```

Prints:

```
         email                date   name completed
1  aaa@xyz.com 2022-01-07 12:10:00  james       yes
4  bbb@xyz.com 2022-02-07 08:04:00  clark       yes
```

---

Or: sort values by `date` and then `.drop_duplicates`:

```py
df = df[df.completed == "yes"].sort_values("date").drop_duplicates(["email", "name"], keep="first")
print(df)
```

---

EDIT: Added `df[df.completed == "yes"]` part.

Comment: Your second answer is the better one, but it's missing the logic of `yes` rows.

Comment: @BeRT2me Yep, you're right, missed that part. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers do not necessarily satisfy the requirement:

> i want to only retain the earliest date when completed = 'yes' and drop all the other rows.

They only work for the example provided given the correct order of the rows. I wouldn't rely on that.

To do so, we first have to select only the rows with `completed == 'yes'`. For instance:

```
res = (
    df[df.completed.eq('yes')]
      .sort_values('date')
      .groupby(['email', 'name'], as_index=False)
      .first()
)
```

However, assuming that there may be groups (`name`, `email`) that do not contain rows with `completed == 'yes'`, but should not be deleted (i.e. only the requirement of the most recent date should be considered in this case) the logic of `sort_values` should be changed:

```
# sort first by df.completed == 'no', then by df.date in ascending order; 
# and then select the first row for each group (name, email)
res = (
    df.sort_values(['completed', 'date'], 
                   key=lambda col: col.eq('no') if col.name == 'completed' else col)
      .groupby(['email', 'name'], as_index=False)
      .first()
)
```

---

Output:

```
>>> res

         email   name                 date completed
0  aaa@xyz.com  james  01-07-2022 12:10:00       yes
1  bbb@xyz.com  clark  02-07-2022 08:04:00       yes
```

Comment: what if i want to filter the column on two values? col.eq('no', 'another value') and when there are two dates for the same email id and different values in the completed column, how to prioritize one over the other